# water stress expression markers in arabidopsis thaliana

Tags: plant-physiology, gene-expression

So far I found papers that show studies using RNA arrays on whom they categorized water stress gene markers in root. Water stresses were reproduced by different protocols (manitol...) but always on several week old plants. Does anyone know any study carried on young (6 days more or less) arabidopsis thaliana plants?